# Requirejs with codeigniter using templates

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, requirejs

I'm using codeigniter with template, and want to know how to use RequireJS to include specific javascript in views. I have a product view, I need to include a javascript inside the body of the template to open when the product view javascript to work, could someone give an example of how to do? Should I change something in the file hooks? How do? Thank you.

Comment: I am guessing there are not a lot of people who know both codeigniter and require.js.  If you can give an example of how you do this sort of thing in codeigniter generally or even take a crack at how you think it might be done with require.js, some of us may be able to help you get the require.js part right.

Comment: Perhaps make a helper that stores all js code and just use it whenever needed? Not sure at all how requirejs works.

Comment: This question is extremely vague and offers no code examples.  Here's how to inlclude RequireJs. `<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/js/require.js"></script>`

Comment: Is there any code to see us

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's CI other frameworks. The JS scripts require the source attr to be loaded. Requirejs works accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need RequireJS for "including specific javascript in views".

Assuming your javascript file in is a folder, e.g. `/scripts/myJavascriptFile.js` and your view is `my_view.php` then you should use `base_url()` using the URL helper.

In `my_view.php`:

```
<html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>scripts/myJavascriptFile.js" ></script>
            <title>...</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        ...
```

And in your controller, before you load the view:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```